# EXT JS : How to conditionally hide an item in combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to sort out below issue.

I have a combobox which is associated with a dataStore which has 3 items. (a,b and c).

I want to hide an item 'c' from the combo box but still want to pre populate (or show) it with value 'c' for the previous records which have chosen item 'C' in past.

Any idea will be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a pickle here.

First of all, removing the item from the store - removes it from the pick list. 
So if your server side populates the data for combobox - just don't include it in the payload.

Second, to show the item anyway, you have to add it back into the store that backs your combobox. You can do that manually, when setting the value of the field, or in the store load listener which triggers after the store is loaded with data from server.

Answer (score 1):

dbrin has given a good way, other way is you do not need to remove that record from store as dbrin told but you need to apply filter to the store. Later when you want to add/display that particular record, just remove/clear filter